# GXT TabPanel bug in firefox

Tags: firefox, gwt, gxt, tabpanel

I've copied Sencha example source ([link](http://www.sencha.com/examples/index.html#ExamplePlace:basictabs)) to my code and has strange black dots near tab headers if i opened app in Firefox. Click on this dots activate the tab next to it. In Chromium all looks nice.

Code example:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
    vp.setSpacing(10);

    String txt = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
            + " Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.";

    TabPanel folder = new TabPanel();
    folder.setWidth(450);

    HTML shortText = new HTML(txt);
    shortText.addStyleName("pad-text");
    folder.add(shortText, "Short Text");

    HTML longText = new HTML(txt + "<br><br>" + txt);
    longText.addStyleName("pad-text");
    folder.add(longText, "Long Text");
    vp.add(folder);
    RootPanel.get().add(vp);
}
```

Firefox:

[image: Firefox:]

Chromium:

[image: Chromium:]

What can I do to avoid this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found solution. All i need was css adding like

```
* {
   margin: 2;
   padding: 0;
}
ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: auto;
}
```

UPD: Wrong. Setup.txt tells

```
2b. Add a stylesheet link to reset.css and ensure it is the first referenced stylesheet:
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{module name}/reset.css" />
```

Comment: Your problem might be solved, but other strange things could appear in the future. These kind of things could happen after a partial GXT upgrade. Are you sure you use the right version of CSS in your project?

Comment: The real fix here is to add the `reset.css` file to your page, either in the html file, or in the gwt module. It will also make the same sorts of changes you are doing here, but will also provide other browser normalization. This is documented in the `setup.txt` file in the gxt download as well as the online getting started guides.